# Wordle game in C++

Tags: c++, game, c++11, wordle

I am a programmer who likes making clones of games. Having completed a version of Wordle in Python, I challenged myself with making a version of it in C++. This includes a solver as well (add a flag *-s* while running to activate solving mode.)

I used ANSI escape codes to create coloring and an interactive experience. However, this might be MacOS only, please advise about this.

Here is the code: (compiled with `g++`, no extra flags)

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  wordle
//
//  Created by Colin Ding on 10/4/22.
//  Copyright © 2022 Colin Ding. All rights reserved.
//

#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// the following are UBUNTU/LINUX, and MacOS ONLY terminal color codes.
#define RESET "\033[0m"
#define BLACK "\033[30m"              /* Black */
#define RED "\033[31m"                /* Red */
#define GREEN "\033[32m"              /* Green */
#define YELLOW "\033[33m"             /* Yellow */
#define BLUE "\033[34m"               /* Blue */
#define MAGENTA "\033[35m"            /* Magenta */
#define CYAN "\033[36m"               /* Cyan */
#define WHITE "\033[37m"              /* White */
#define BOLDBLACK "\033[1m\033[30m"   /* Bold Black */
#define BOLDRED "\033[1m\033[31m"     /* Bold Red */
#define BOLDGREEN "\033[1m\033[32m"   /* Bold Green */
#define BOLDYELLOW "\033[1m\033[33m"  /* Bold Yellow */
#define BOLDBLUE "\033[1m\033[34m"    /* Bold Blue */
#define BOLDMAGENTA "\033[1m\033[35m" /* Bold Magenta */
#define BOLDCYAN "\033[1m\033[36m"    /* Bold Cyan */
#define BOLDWHITE "\033[1m\033[37m"   /* Bold White */
#define DIMBLACK "\033[2m\033[30m"    /* Dim Black */
#define DIMRED "\033[2m\033[31m"      /* Dim Red */
#define DIMGREEN "\033[2m\033[32m"    /* Dim Green */
#define DIMYELLOW "\033[2m\033[33m"   /* Dim Yellow */
#define DIMBLUE "\033[2m\033[34m"     /* Dim Blue */
#define DIMMAGENTA "\033[2m\033[35m"  /* Dim Magenta */
#define DIMCYAN "\033[2m\033[36m"     /* Dim Cyan */
#define DIMWHITE "\033[2m\033[37m"    /* Dim White */
#define MOVEUP "\033["                /* add integer, and add F */
#define ERASELINE "\033[2K"           /* erase current line */

const int LENGTH = 5;

struct {
    char wrong = '_';
    char in_word = 'O';
    char correct = '#';
} LETTERVALUES;

std::string KEYBOARDCOLORS[] = {
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE,
    WHITE};

std::vector<std::string> readSolutions(int length) {
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("./words/solutions.txt");

    while (getline(fin, line)) {
        if (line.length() == length) {
            vec.push_back(line);
        }
    }

    fin.close();

    return vec;
}

std::vector<std::string> readGuesses(int length) {
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("./words/guesses.txt");

    while (getline(fin, line)) {
        if (line.length() == length) {
            vec.push_back(line);
        }
    }

    fin.close();

    return vec;
}

std::string chooseRandom(std::vector<std::string> vec) {
    auto iterator = vec.begin();
    int random_number = rand() % vec.size();

    advance(iterator, random_number);

    return iterator[0];
}

char getNthLetter(int n) {
    return "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[n - 1];
}

int getNumFromChar(char x) {
    return ((int)x) - 64;
}

std::string checkWord(std::string text, std::string correct, int len) {
    std::string out;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char text_character = text[i];
        char correct_character = correct[i];

        if (text_character == correct_character) {
            out += LETTERVALUES.correct;  // string(GREEN) + LETTERVALUES.correct + string(RESET);
            correct[i] = '0';
        } else if (correct.find(text_character) != std::string::npos) {
            out += LETTERVALUES.in_word;  // string(YELLOW) + LETTERVALUES.in_word + string(RESET);
            correct[i] = '0';
        } else {
            out += LETTERVALUES.wrong;  // string(DIMWHITE) + LETTERVALUES.wrong + string(RESET);
        }
    }

    return out;
}

std::string getKeyboardForPrinting() {
    std::string out;
    int i = 0;

    for (auto color : KEYBOARDCOLORS) {
        out += std::string(color) + getNthLetter(i) + std::string(RESET);
        i++;
    }

    return out;
}

void play(std::string solution, std::vector<std::string> all_guesses) {
    std::cout << BOLDWHITE;
    std::cout << "Welcome to Wordle!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Play by guessing 5-letter words." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The feedback will give you clues:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " GRAY   = Character not in word at all" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " GREEN  = Character found and position correct" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " YELLOW = Character found but position incorrect" << std::endl;
    std::cout << RESET;

    std::cout << "\n\n";
    std::cout << getKeyboardForPrinting() << std::endl;

    int lines_since_keyboard = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        std::string guess;

        std::cout << BOLDWHITE << "Guess a word (" + std::to_string(i + 1) + "/6): " << RESET;
        std::cin >> guess;
        transform(guess.begin(), guess.end(), guess.begin(), ::toupper);

        lines_since_keyboard++;

        if (guess == "STOP") {
            return;
        }

        if (find(all_guesses.begin(), all_guesses.end(), guess) != all_guesses.end()) {
            std::string feedback = checkWord(guess, solution, LENGTH);

            std::string to_write = "Guess a word (" + std::to_string(i + 1) + "/6): ";

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                char inputted_character = guess[j];
                char feedback_character = feedback[j];

                int keyboard_colors_index = getNumFromChar(inputted_character);  // inputted_character);

                std::string color_to_make;

                if (feedback_character == LETTERVALUES.wrong) {
                    color_to_make = DIMWHITE;
                } else if (feedback_character == LETTERVALUES.correct) {
                    color_to_make = GREEN;
                } else if (feedback_character == LETTERVALUES.in_word) {
                    color_to_make = YELLOW;
                } else {
                    color_to_make = BLACK;
                }

                to_write += color_to_make + inputted_character + RESET;

                if (KEYBOARDCOLORS[keyboard_colors_index] == WHITE) {
                    KEYBOARDCOLORS[keyboard_colors_index] = color_to_make;
                } else if (KEYBOARDCOLORS[keyboard_colors_index] != GREEN) {
                    if ((KEYBOARDCOLORS[keyboard_colors_index] != RED) && (color_to_make == GREEN)) {
                        KEYBOARDCOLORS[keyboard_colors_index] = color_to_make;
                    }
                } else {
                    KEYBOARDCOLORS[keyboard_colors_index] = color_to_make;
                }
            }

            std::cout << std::string(MOVEUP) + "1F";
            std::cout << to_write << std::endl;

            std::cout << std::string(MOVEUP) + std::to_string(lines_since_keyboard) + "F";
            std::cout << getKeyboardForPrinting() << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::string(MOVEUP) + std::to_string(lines_since_keyboard) + "E";

            if (guess == solution) {
                std::cout << "You won in " << i + 1 << " moves!" << std::endl;
                return;
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << std::string(MOVEUP) + "1F";
            std::cout << ERASELINE;

            std::cout << "Guess a word (" + std::to_string(i + 1) + "/6): " << BOLDRED << "INVALID";
            std::cout << std::string(MOVEUP) + "1E";

            i--;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "You lost!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The correct word was " << solution << std::endl;
}

void printHelpExit() {
    std::cout << "Usage: wordle [-h|--help] [-s|--showsolution]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Option\t\t\tBehavior" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------\t\t\t--------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-s, -showsolution\tShow the solution at beginning (debug)" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "-h, --help\t\tPrint this help text and quit" << std::endl;

    exit(0);
}

bool contains(std::vector<char> c, char e) {
    return find(begin(c), end(c), e) != end(c);
};

std::vector<std::string> applyRule(std::vector<std::string> all_words, std::vector<char> s1, std::vector<char> s2, std::vector<char> s3, std::vector<char> s4, std::vector<char> s5) {
    std::vector<std::string> new_solutions;

    std::copy_if(all_words.begin(), all_words.end(), back_inserter(new_solutions),
                 [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5](std::string const& x) { return (contains(s1, x[0]) && (contains(s2, x[1])) && (contains(s3, x[2])) && (contains(s4, x[3])) && (contains(s5, x[4]))); });

    return new_solutions;
}

void solver(std::vector<std::string> all_solutions, bool log_s) {
    std::cout << BOLDCYAN;
    std::cout << "Welcome to the Wordle solver!!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "To use this solver, simply follow the instructions;" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Input the word it suggests in your game:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Make sure to give the program the feedback!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "'_' = gray tile" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "'+' = yellow tile" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "'=' = green tile" << std::endl;

    std::cout << RESET;

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    std::vector<char> s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;

    char letters[26] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

    for (char c : letters) {
        s1.push_back(c);
        s2.push_back(c);
        s3.push_back(c);
        s4.push_back(c);
        s5.push_back(c);
    }

    std::cout << BOLDMAGENTA;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        std::string response, chosen_word;

        if (i == 0) {
            chosen_word = "CRATE";
        } else {
            chosen_word = chooseRandom(all_solutions);
        }

        while (response.size() != 5) {
            if (response == "STOP") {
                return;
            } else {
                if (response == "LIST") {
                    // todo, pritn all_solutions
                }
                std::cout << "Try the word " + chosen_word + ": ";
                std::cin >> response;
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            std::vector<char>* to_change = nullptr;
            std::vector<char>* all[5] = {&s1, &s2, &s3, &s4, &s5};

            if (j == 0) {
                to_change = &s1;
            } else if (j == 1) {
                to_change = &s2;
            } else if (j == 2) {
                to_change = &s3;
            } else if (j == 3) {
                to_change = &s4;
            } else if (j == 4) {
                to_change = &s5;
            }

            char resp_c = response[j];
            char word_c = chosen_word[j];

            if (resp_c == '=') {
                to_change->clear();
                to_change->push_back(word_c);
            } else if (resp_c == '-') {
                to_change->erase(remove(to_change->begin(), to_change->end(), word_c), to_change->end());

                for (std::vector<char>* v : all) {
                    if (v == to_change) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    v->erase(remove(v->begin(), v->end(), word_c), v->end());
                }
            } else if (resp_c == '+') {
                (*to_change).erase(remove(to_change->begin(), to_change->end(), word_c), to_change->end());

                for (std::vector<char>* v : all) {
                    if (v == to_change) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    v->push_back(word_c);
                    std::sort(v->begin(), v->end());
                    v->erase(unique(v->begin(), v->end()), v->end());
                }
            } else {
                std::cout << "Invalid input format, exiting." << std::endl;
            }
        }

        if (log_s) {
            for (char c : s1) {
                std::cout << c;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            for (char c : s2) {
                std::cout << c;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            for (char c : s3) {
                std::cout << c;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            for (char c : s4) {
                std::cout << c;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            for (char c : s5) {
                std::cout << c;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        all_solutions = applyRule(all_solutions, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);

        if (all_solutions.size() == 1) {
            std::cout << "The solution is " << all_solutions[0] << "." << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    srand(time(0));
    bool show_sol = false;
    bool solver_on = false;
    bool show_alpha = false;

    if (argc > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            std::string arg = argv[i];

            if ((arg == "-h") || (arg == "--help")) {
                printHelpExit();
            } else if ((arg == "-d") || (arg == "--debug")) {
                std::cout << BOLDBLUE << "DEBUG ON" << RESET << std::endl;
                show_sol = true;
            } else if ((arg == "-s") || (arg == "--solver")) {
                std::cout << BOLDBLUE << "SOLVER ON" << RESET << std::endl;
                solver_on = true;
            } else if (arg == "--showalpha") {
                std::cout << BOLDBLUE << "SHOWING ALPHA" << RESET << std::endl;
                show_alpha = true;
            } else {
                std::cout << "Invalid argument: " << arg << std::endl;
                printHelpExit();
            }
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::string> all_solutions = readSolutions(LENGTH);
    std::vector<std::string> all_guesses = readGuesses(LENGTH);

    for (std::string s : all_solutions) {
        all_guesses.push_back(s);
    }

    auto const solution = chooseRandom(all_solutions);

    if (show_sol == true) {
        std::cout << BOLDGREEN << solution << RESET << std::endl;
    }

    if (solver_on == false) {
        play(solution, all_guesses);
    } else {
        solver(all_solutions, show_alpha);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**words/guesses.txt**
[download from github](https://github.com/colding10/wordle/blob/2bf4dd0da85bdb938a9ca09f71b30f6c10902133/guesses.txt)

**words/solutions.txt**
[download from github](https://github.com/colding10/wordle/blob/2bf4dd0da85bdb938a9ca09f71b30f6c10902133/solutions.txt)

Comment: I can't include the word files (too long). adding a link instead.

Comment: Ewww, hard-coded terminal-specific escape codes.  Can't you use termcap or similar, to adapt to the actual `$TERM` that's present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Avoid macros

Avoid preprocessor macros where possible. They have various issues if you don't use them carefully, and they are rarely needed in C++. To define constants, create `static constexpr` variables, for example:

```
static constexpr auto RESET = "\033[0m";
```

## Keeping track of colors

There are several issues with your array `KEYBOARDCOLORS[]`. First, how many elements does it have? Are you sure you wrote `WHITE` exactly 26 times? At the very least, specify the size explicitly, like you did for `letters[]`:

```
std::string KEYBOARDCOLORS[26] = {...};
```

That way, if you add too many colors, a compile error will occur, but it's still not ideal that you still have to write `WHITE` 26 times, and if you miss one there will be an empty color string (although at least that won't cause anything to crash).

If you use `std::vector` here, you can initialize all elements to the same value:

```
std::vector<std::string> KEYBOARDCOLORS(26, WHITE);
```

But there are still many issues. You are sometimes comparing colors against each other, but since you store them as strings, it has to do string comparison. That is less efficient than possible. Finally, you are assuming that you can print strings containing ANSI escape codes to change colors. But if you were to port your program to something that uses a different way of changing colors, you could not use strings any more, and you would have to change a lot of code.

It helps to add a layer of indirection here. Create an `enum class` of color names:

```
enum class Color {
    BLACK,
    RED,
    GREEN,
    ⋮
};
```

Then you can write:

```
std::vector<Color> KEYBOARDCOLORS(26, Color::WHITE);
```

Comparing enums (which are just integers under the hood) is very efficient on a CPU:

```
if (KEYBOARDCOLORS[keyboard_colors_index] == Color::WHITE) {
```

Then the only remaining issue is converting this enum to an ANSI escape code. I would write a function `colorToAnsi()` that does this. It could look like:

```
std::string colorToAnsi(Color color) {
    switch (color) {
    case Color::BLACK: return "\033[30m";
    case Color::RED: return "\033[31m";
    ⋮
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < KEYBOARDCOLORS.size(); ++i) {
    out += colorToAnsi(KEYBOARDCOLORS[i]) + getNthLetter(i);
}

out += RESET;
```

I also wonder why you added constants for so many colors, when you only use five of them?

## Consider using a curses library

If you want to have a terminal application with colors, and maybe also the ability to clear the screen and draw text at arbitrary positions, consider using a [curses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)). These provide a platform-independent API to do these things.

## Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`

[Prefer to use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](//stackoverflow.com/q/213907); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually unnecessary and might be detrimental for performance.

## Avoid code duplication

Writing the same code over and over is boring, tedious, and it increases the chance that you make a mistake somewhere. So try to find ways to avoid doing that, like with the initialization of `KEYBOARDCOLORS[]` I mentioned above.

Another example of repetition is `readSolutions()` and `readGuesses()`. These two functions do exactly the same thing, the only difference is the filename they use. So consider creating one function that takes the filename as a parameter:

```
std::vector<std::string> readFile(const std::string& filename, int length) {
    ⋮
    std::ifstream fin(filename);
    ⋮
}
⋮
auto all_solutions = readFile("../words/solutions.txt", LENGTH);
auto all_sguesses = readFile("../words/guesses.txt", LENGTH);
```

Also, whenever you have a bunch of variables that start with the same name and end in different numbers, you probably should have created an array or vector. So instead of `s1, s2, ...` write:

```
std::vector<char> s[5];
```

Or even better, consider that a `std::vector<char>` is more or less a `std::string`, and that you want to print the contents of `s` if `log_s == true`, so you can simplify things a lot by writing:

```
const std::string letters = "ABCDE...";
std::vector<std::string> s(5, letters);
⋮
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    auto& to_change = s[j];
    ⋮
}
⋮
if (log_s) {
    for (auto& to_show: s) {
        std::cout << to_show << '\n';
    }
}
```

## Naming things

Most things in your code have names that rather clearly indicate what they do or mean. But there are some examples of unnecessarily short variable names, like `s` and `s1`…`s5`. Make sure you give these variables names that are meaningful.

Note that it's fine to use `i` and `j` for loop indices; this is a very common use so their meaning will be clear to most programmers.